# Insert date values in a created table

Tags: insert

I have created a table using the below query

```
CREATE TABLE job_history (
  EMPLOYEE_ID decimal(6,0) NOT NULL,
  START_DATE date NOT NULL,
  END_DATE date  NOT NULL,
  JOB_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  DEPARTMENT_ID decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID,START_DATE)
  )
```

And when I try to update values in the created table using the below query

```
INSERT INTO job_history VALUES
(102, '1993-01-13', '1998-07-24', 'IT_PROG', 60),
(101, '1989-09-21', '1993-10-27', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 111),
(103, '1993-10-28', '1997-03-15', 'AC_MGR', 110),
(201, '1996-02-17', '1999-12-19', 'MK_REP', 20),
(114, '1998-03-24', '1999-12-31', 'ST_CLERK', 51),
(122, '1999-01-01', '1999-12-31', 'ST_CLERK', 50),
(200, '1987-09-17', '1993-06-17', 'AD_ASST', 90),
(176, '1998-03-24', '1998-12-31', 'SA_REP', 80),
(175, '1999-01-01', '1999-12-31', 'SA_MAN', 81),
(201, '1994-07-01', '1998-12-31', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 91),
(0, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', 0)
```

I get an error saying "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."  how to resolve this? I tried it for .

Comment: Change '0000-00-00' to a date that that can be represented by the `DATE` datatype like '18990101'

Comment: `'0000-00-00'` is an invalid date. If you don't have a value, then just store `NULL`. Also: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Once you create table use query below yo add first 10 records into table *

> *job_history*

```
INSERT INTO job_history VALUES
(102, '19930113', '19980724', 'IT_PROG', 60),
(101, '19890921', '19931027', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 111),
(103, '19931028', '19970315', 'AC_MGR', 110),
(201, '19960217', '19991219', 'MK_REP', 20),
(114, '19980324', '19991231', 'ST_CLERK', 51),
(122, '19990101', '19991231', 'ST_CLERK', 50),
(200, '19870917', '19930617', 'AD_ASST', 90),
(176, '19980324', '19981231', 'SA_REP', 80),
(175, '19990101', '19991231', 'SA_MAN', 81),
(201, '19940701', '19981231', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 91)
```

You will not be able to insert last raw `(0, '00000000', '00000000', '', 0)` as its not a valid date format.

and after that once you insert 10 rows you can query it to see `SELECT * FROM job_history` and you will find results below.

[image]